# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'where')

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Would like to ask solution on uncaught TypeError where my html run "a" and "b"/"c" for the first time the page is load, then on my search condition, it will run "d" "e", when in search condition display unit not equal to "CASES", it runs fine where it will go var option and display the table. But when it met the condition "CASES", it shows *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'where')  LINE "options1.where = data.field;"*

```js
layui.use(['form', 'element', 'laydate', 'jquery', 'layer', 'table'], function () {
    var $ = layui.jquery,
        layer = layui.layer,
        form = layui.form,
        table = layui.table,
        searchDate = '';
        var laydate = layui.laydate;
        laydate.render({
            elem: '#reportDate', 
            lang: 'en',
            done: function (value) {
                console.log(value); 
                searchDate = value;
            }
        });   
var displayUnit = $('[name=displayUnit]').val();
console.log("a" + displayUnit);
if (displayUnit == "CASES") {
  console.log("b" + displayUnit);
  var options1 = {
    elem: '#resultMonitoringTable',
    id: 'resultMonitoring',
    limit: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    page: false,
    loading: true,
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../collection/resultMonitoringData',
    response: {
      statusName: 'code',
      dataName: 'data',
      statusCode: 200,
      msgName: 'message',
      countName: 'totalCount'
    },
    cols: [
      [{
          title: 'Select',
          width: '10%',
          align: 'center',
          toolbar: '#orderListBar'
        },
        {
          field: 'delinquency',
          title: 'Delinquency',
          width: '15%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            var delinquency = s.delinquency;
            if (delinquency === '6') {
              result = 'M7';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '0') {
              result = 'M1';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '1') {
              result = 'M2';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '2') {
              result = 'M3';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '3') {
              result = 'M4';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '4') {
              result = 'M5';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '5') {
              result = 'M6';
              return result;
            } else {
              result = '>=M8';
              return result;
            }

          }
        },
        {
          field: 'cases',
          title: 'Cases',
          width: '20%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {

            result = s.cases;
            return result;
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'billing',
          hide: true,
          templet: function(s) {

            result = formatMoney(s.billing);
            return result;
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'collection',
          title: 'Collected',
          width: '20%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            result = formatMoney(s.collection);
            return result;
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'billing' && 'collection',
          title: 'Balance',
          width: '20%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            result = formatMoney(s.billing - s.collection);
            return result;
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'billing' && 'balance',
          title: 'Pct%',
          width: '15%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            result = formatMoney((s.collection / s.billing) * 100) + '%';
            return result;
          }
        },

      ]
    ],
    done: function(res) {
      data = res.data;
      console.log("result: " + data);
    }
  };
  table.render(options1);
} else {
  console.log("c" + displayUnit);
  var options = {
    elem: '#resultMonitoringTable',
    id: 'resultMonitoring',
    limit: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    page: false,
    loading: true,
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../collection/resultMonitoringData',
    response: {
      statusName: 'code',
      dataName: 'data',
      statusCode: 200,
      msgName: 'message',
      countName: 'totalCount'
    },
    cols: [
      [{
          title: 'Select',
          width: '10%',
          align: 'center',
          toolbar: '#orderListBar'
        },
        {
          field: 'delinquency',
          title: 'Delinquency',
          width: '15%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            var delinquency = s.delinquency;
            if (delinquency === '6') {
              result = 'M7';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '0') {
              result = 'M1';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '1') {
              result = 'M2';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '2') {
              result = 'M3';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '3') {
              result = 'M4';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '4') {
              result = 'M5';
              return result;
            } else if (delinquency === '5') {
              result = 'M6';
              return result;
            } else {
              result = '>=M8';
              return result;
            }

          }
        },

        {
          field: 'billing',
          title: 'Billing',
          width: '20%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {

            result = formatMoney(s.billing);
            return result;
          }
        },

        {
          field: 'collection',
          title: 'Collected',
          width: '20%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            result = formatMoney(s.collection);
            return result;
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'billing' && 'collection',
          title: 'Balance',
          width: '20%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            result = formatMoney(s.billing - s.collection);
            return result;
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'billing' && 'balance',
          title: 'Pct%',
          width: '15%',
          align: 'center',
          templet: function(s) {
            result = formatMoney((s.collection / s.billing) * 100) + '%';
            return result;
          }
        },

      ]
    ],
    done: function(res) {
      data = res.data;
      console.log("result: " + data);
    }
  };

  table.render(options);
}

form.on('submit(search)', function(data) {

  if (searchDate.length === 0) {
    layer.msg('Report Date can\'t be empty!', {
      icon: 2
    });
  }
  var displayUnit = $('[name=displayUnit]').val();
  if (displayUnit == "CASES") {
    console.log(data);
    options1.where = data.field;
    console.log("d" + displayUnit);
    table.reload('resultMonitoring', options1);
  } else {
    console.log("e" + displayUnit);
    console.log(data);
    options.where = data.field;
    table.reload('resultMonitoring', options);
  }
   table.on('tool(resultMonitoringTable)', function (obj) {
                var data = obj.data; 
                var layEvent = obj.event; 
                 var reportDate = $('[name=reportDate]').val();
                 var displayUnit = $('[name=displayUnit]').val();
                 console.log("report date and display unit" +reportDate+displayUnit);
                if (layEvent == "view") {
                    console.log("view: " + data.delinquency + reportDate);
                    location.href = '/collection/view?delinquency='+ data.delinquency+'&reportDate='+data.reportDate+'&displayUnit='+data.displayUnit;
                    
                }
            });

   function formatMoney(amount, decimalCount = 2, decimal = ".", thousands = ",") {
        try {
            decimalCount = Math.abs(decimalCount);
            decimalCount = isNaN(decimalCount) ? 2 : decimalCount;

            const negativeSign = amount < 0 ? "-" : "";

            let i = parseInt(amount = Math.abs(Number(amount) || 0).toFixed(decimalCount)).toString();
            let j = (i.length > 3) ? i.length % 3 : 0;

            return negativeSign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousands : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousands) + (decimalCount ? decimal + Math.abs(amount - i).toFixed(decimalCount).slice(2) : "");
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: There is a problem that `field: 'billing' && 'balance',` sets `field` to 'balance' and `field: 'billing' && 'collection'` set the `field` property to 'collection'. When faced with bugs of unknown causes in a program with known faults that might cause bugs, fix the known faults first.

Comment: Can the user change the display unit? If so, how do you run the setup code (before the `form.on(.,,)` line after the display unit has been changed., Please take the [tour], read about [minimal and sufficient code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to rework the question with details needed by readership to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @traktor for correcting me. I deleted my answer as it was not only wrong but possibly misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, apology for not include the full code examples. I have edited and include the full code sample.

Comment: @ndc Sorry, I'm confused - how does the value of `[name=displayUnit]` get changed, and how does changing it cause the code branch starting `else {  console.log(...);  var options = {...` to be executed? Without a **minimalistic, cutdown** piece of code, with some HTML to demonstrate the problem (not layers of the application) it is difficult to _guess_ what is going wrong. So far all we have is that `options1` hasn't been set.